# How to set a ref.current on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

EDIT: it should be show / hide 'Hi' on click of 'Open' so basically clicking 'Open' is equivalent to clicking 'Hello', I'm sorry.

I have a `<details>` element and a `<p>` element, what I want to do is on click of the `<Menu />` component, toggle the `<Details />` component on and off (show / hide 'Hi' on click of 'Hello'). Here is the code I've tried:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Menu = ({ toggleDetails }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={toggleDetails}>Open</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Details = (isOpen) => {
  const detailsRef = useRef();
  // detailsRef.current.open = isOpen;
  return (
    <details ref={detailsRef}>
      <summary>Hello</summary>
      <div>Hi</div>
    </details>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleDetails = () => {
    setIsOpen(isOpen ? false : true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Details isOpen={isOpen} />
      <Menu toggleDetails={toggleDetails} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

A code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-25ott?file=/index.js

I feel I'm close, on change of `isOpen` state, the Details component is re-rendered and I want to toggle `detailsRef.current.open` to `true` or `false`, but `detailsRef.current` is `undefined` so the commented line does not work, how can I achieve this?

Comment: So you have an `onClick` function on the `<p>` in menu, but you're also talking about having an `onClick` on the `<summary>` in `Details`, but there's no onClick there.  I'm a little confused as to exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SethLutske So sorry, should be onclick of 'open' show/hide 'Hi', so basically clicking of 'open' should be equivalent to clicking 'Hello'

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what I think you mean when you say "toggle details on and off", you're looking for a [conditional render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleDetails = () => {
    setIsOpen(isOpen ? false : true);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {isOpen && <Details />}
      <Menu toggleDetails={toggleDetails} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You don't need a ref at all, nor does `Details` need the `isOpen` prop.

To toggle the visibility of hi on click of hello, you would do the same:

```js
const Details = (isOpen) => {
  const [showHi, setShowHi] = useState(true)

  return (
    <details>
      <summary onClick={() => setShowHi(!showHi)}>Hello</summary>
      {showHi && <div>Hi</div>}
    </details>
  );
};
```

Comment: No, I meant click at the 'Hello' and show/hide 'Hi'

Comment: Ok...that's not super clear in the question. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I removed the useRef and added this `{isOpen ? <div>Hi</div> : null}` to conditional render, but it still does not work.

Comment: The `details` tag is preventing the conditional rendering, I tried to replace details with `div` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

to set a ref.current on click?...

```
onClick={() => { ref.current = false;}
```

If you don't want the whole page to refresh like it does when using setState use useRef instead.